# Deleting Backbone.js models with cid

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, backbone.js, jasmine

I am trying to delete a model that I create in backbone. I am not trying to do away with the model itself.

this is what I have: A jasmine unit test to the code first

```
    it("should delete the current Box ", function () {
        var myContainer = new App.Container();
        var myBox = new App.Box();
        myBox.setTitle("The First Box");
        expect(myBox.attributes.title).toBeDefined();
        **myContainer.deleteBox(myBox);**

        expect(myBox.attributes.title).toBeUndefined();
    });
```

Now the code:

```
App.Container = Backbone.Model.extend({

    defaults: {
        type: "1.0",
        selectedBox: 0,
        boxes: [],
        labels: [],

    },

    deleteBox: function () {
        this.destroy({
            success: function() {
                console.log("the box has been removed");
                //Array reindexed
            }
        });
    }
});
```

It does not work. the jasmine unit test fails and I think I have to some how delete the object at the cid given by backbone. Im not sure how to go about it. any suggestions?

Comment: Did you mean `box.destroy`?

Comment: because if we delete myBox, then myBox.attributes.title is undefined!

Comment: box.destroy does not work... i have to some how delete using the cid I think

Comment: Then why do you expect `deleteBox` to delete `box` at all? It just ignores the argument. `box.destroy` doesn't pass your test, or doesn't delete `box`?

Comment: i tried box.destroy with the argument box being passed. box.destroy does not delete myBox, I checked. So, it is supposed to fail. I am still new to backbone MVC and what to know what to do in this case.

Comment: in fact, I tried all this before posting the question.

Comment: what are trying to accomplish by deleting the object: 1- delete it from server, 2- remove it from a collection 3- reset its properties 4- deallocate memory occupied by the object?

Comment: remove it from the collection

Answer (score 1):

1. It looks like you are misusing a Backbone Model in your use of Container. It would be much better practice to make the box a view that has its own model, and the container a view that has a Box Collection assigned to it and iterates through creating and then managing your boxes. You can assign listeners to the collection to choose when to delete a box.
2. You call `myContainer.deleteBox(myBox);`, but then don't receive the box passed as a parameter!

#### UPDATE

In response to your note, I do understand - it does take some head-wrapping to get used to the concepts in Backbone.

If I understand what you are trying to do, here's some sample code that you can chew on that gives a bit of a better idea of how to accomplish this kind of thing:

```
App.Boxes = Backbone.Collection.extend({}) 
App.Box = Backbone.View.extend({});        // Child view for each model
App.Container = Backbone.View.extend({     // 'Collection view', that draws 
                                           // each child view.
  tagName: 'div',
  
  initialize: function(){
    
    this.boxes = {};

    // Assign event listeners to redraw DOM when your models change.
    this.listenTo(App.boxes, 'add', this.addBox);
    this.listenTo(App.boxes, 'remove', this.removeBox);
    
  },
  
  // Create a new box when a new model is added to the collection.
  addBox: function(model) {

    var newBox = new App.Box({ model: model });

    this.boxes[model.cid] = newBox;
    this.$el.append(newBox.render().el);

    },
  
  // Remove a box when a model is removed from the collection.
  removeBox: function(model) {
    var box = this.boxes[model.cid];
    box.remove();
  },
  

});

// Let's make the parent view.
var myContainer = new App.Container();
$(body).append(myContainer.render().el);

// Make a new collection
App.boxes = new App.Boxes();

// Add models to the collection
App.boxes.add({ title: 'The First Box', });
App.boxes.add({ title: 'The Second Box', });

// Remove a model from the collection.
App.boxes.findWhere({ title: 'The First Box' }).remove();
```

Does this help?

Comment: As for 1, I do push myBox to the Boxes array. I just did not display that code here. as for your other points. Ill get back to you

Comment: yes, I know. You have to actually receive the parameter and then do something with it for it to work. But, I think I need to re think backbone implementation as in point 2